# Js countdown only counts down once

Tags: javascript, html

So I am making a javascript countdown that counts down to zero then switches the text inside a div so that the user can continue. Here is my code:

```
<div id="top">
    You will be redirected in 10..
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        var timerId = 0;

            if(timerId == 0){
                timerId = window.setInterval(function() {
                    var timeCounter = 10;
                    var updateTime = parseInt(timeCounter,10) - 1;
                    $("#top").html("You will be redirected in " + updateTime + "...");

                    if(updateTime <= 0){
                        clearTimeout(timerId);
                        $("#top").html("Click to continue");
                    }
                }, 1000);
            }

     });
</script>
```

It works but only counts down from 10 to 9. Why is this?

Answer (score 2):

`Timecounter` is inside the interval, setting it to ten on every iteration. To make it count down, you would have to move the timecounter variable outside the interval function:

```
<div id="top">
    You will be redirected in 10..
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        var timeCounter = 10,
            timerId = setInterval(function() {
               $("#top").html("You will be redirected in " + ( timeCounter-- ) + "...");
                if(timeCounter <= 0){
                    clearTimeout(timerId);
                    $("#top").html("Click to continue");
                }
            }, 1000);
     });
</script>
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/f7uUL/1/)

Comment: You might end up with a better score if you didn't play the Fastest Gun in the West and fire up a hasty but incomrehensible answer.

Comment: @JanDvorak - My answer was right though, and just stating that the variable should be moved to a different scope should be enough, and now I've even added some code and a fiddle.

Comment: It was correct, but it was very hard to understand (the formulation, not the idea)

Comment: I still suggest you don't play the FGITW.

Answer (score 1):

Each time the timer elapses it runs the specified callback.

And inside the callback (which is a new instance of the given function each time) you set `timeCounter` to ten.

Hence the value always stays the same.

Answer (score 1):

You need to bring the time counter outside the window.setInterval() function.

It can remain just inside the ready function but outside the setInterval() method.

Answer (score 1):

You hardcode your timeCount variable. My solution:

Html code:

```
<div id="top">
    You will be redirected in <span id="timer">10<span>..
</div>
```

Javascript code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        window.setInterval(function() {
            var timeCounter = $('#timer').html();
            var updateTime = parseInt(timeCounter,10) - 1;
            $("#timer").html(updateTime);

            if(updateTime <= 0){                    
                $("#top").html("Click to continue");
            }
        }, 1000);


});
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/ccAz6/1/

Answer (score 1):

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/nRPbf/)**

```
var timerId = 0;

var timeCounter=10;

$(document).ready(function(){

            if(timerId == 0){
                timerId = window.setInterval(function() {

                    var updateTime = parseInt(timeCounter) - 1;
                    timeCounter--;

                   $("#top").html("You will be redirected in " + updateTime + "...");

                    if(updateTime <= 0){
                        clearTimeout(timerId);
                        $("#top").html("Click to continue");
                    }
                }, 1000);
            }

     });
```